# ADConnect Sync Mobile Rule

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I am trying to sync the Mobile which is under "Telephones" with Office365 with Mobile section. I created a rule to join the Mobile but it does not work. How can I add a rule to sync Mobile with Office365?

Comment: For whatever reason the Mobile does not sync with Office365....

Comment: I think the answer to that can be found in [this  blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/timmcmic/2018/07/01/office-365-the-mystery-of-mobile-phone/):
_"This is by design.  When the mobile phone number was adjusted in Azure Active Directory the source of authority was changed from on premises to Azure Active Directory.  When Azure Active Directory Sync pushes any changes of the mobile attribute from on premises to Office 365 – Azure Active Directory ignores the change."_